# Bash one-liner to replace all [:punct:] characters with those same characters escaped

Tags: regex, bash, string-substitution

my current kind of unsolved problem with bash is how to replace all the characters in the `[:punct:]` class, that is

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

, each with the same character escaped by a backslash. For example, I want `^h?e.l*l+o:` to become `\^h\?e\.l\*l\+o\:`.

I can do it in a multi-liner fashion with loops. Is it possible to do it in a more succint and elegant way?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Are you sure you need to escape *all* punctuation, or just ones that have special meaning in some context? What's the use case? (There may be various simple alternatives depending on exactly *why* they need to be escaped.)

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) help any?

Comment: @chepner You may be right. I tried to escape all punctuation just for simplicity, but I have a problem with the apostrophe ' (and maybe some other characters that I haven't tested yet) that doesn't match anymore with itself if escaped. I basically want to escape regex and glob metacharacters. The simplest solution is to remove them as in `[!#$%&()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_{|}~]`. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Yes, there are many other approaches as in the post quoted by @EtanReisner two comments above. Thanks, I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Can you use `sed`?

```
echo '^h?e.l*l+o:' | sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\)/\\\1/g'
```

Without `sed`, I can't think of anything else than looping over the characters:

```
s='^h?e.l*l+o:'
o=''
for ((i=0; i<${#s}; i++)) ; do
    c=${s:i:1}
    [[ $c =~ [[:punct:]] ]] && o+=\\
    o+=$c
done
echo "$o"
```

Another possibility is to use Perl's [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta):

```
echo '^h?e.l*l+o:' | perl -lne 'print quotemeta'
```

`-l` handles newlines. `-n` process the input line by line.

Comment: yeah, I believed it could be done with sed and that's why I asked, but I couldn't figure out how since I'm quite new to bash, sed, awk etc. Can you add a bit of explanation on how this works and what does `\1` mean? This was the fastest reply ever, thanks!

Comment: @the_eraser: Check the update - was that your solution?

Comment: @the_eraser: `\1` is the first matching group, i.e. the substring matched by the first pair of `\(...\)`.

Comment: ok, thanks. Yes, I solved with a for loops, slicing the string and `=~`, but using sed is a lot nicer.

Comment: Can just use `&` and no matching group.

Comment: yes `echo '^h?e.l*l+o:' | sed 's/[[:punct:]]/\\&/g'` works. What does & mean?

Comment: `&` refers to the entire string matched by the regex